# Array of objects find key name and merge the values

Tags: javascript, node.js

My array like is:

```
array = [{
  "name": "obj0_property0",
  "url": "picture1"
}, {
  "name": "obj1_property0",
  "url": "picture1"
}, {
  "name": "obj0_property1",
  "url": "picture2"
}]
```

I want output like this in JavaScript:

```
array[{
  "obj0": ["picture1","picture2"]
}, {
  "obj1": ["picture1"]
}]
```

I want to find array key name `obj0` and `obj1` and merge picture values

Comment: `{"obj0":"picture1","picture2"}` is not a valid object. Please test your code before posting.

Comment: What have you tired so far ? post the code you have written so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `Array.prototype.reduce()` may regroup your source array easily:

```js
const array = [{"name":"obj0_property0","url":"picture1"},{"name":"obj1_property0","url":"picture1"},{"name":"obj0_property1","url":"picture2"}],
      result = array.reduce((r,{name,url}) => {
        const [key] = name.split('_'),
              match = r.find(item => key in item)
        match ? match[key].push(url) : r.push({[key]:[url]})
        return r
      },[])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` is a good method for transforming arrays

```js
var array = [{"name":"obj0_property0","url":"picture1"},{"name":"obj1_property0","url":"picture1"},{"name":"obj0_property1","url":"picture2"}]

var result = array.reduce((acc, {name, url}) => {
  // getting object key obj0, obj1
  const objKey = name.split(`_`)[0];
  
  // trying to find in accumulator object with same key as objKey
  const objInArray = acc.find(accitem => objKey in accitem);

  // if found
  if (objInArray) {
    // add another url
    objInArray[objKey].push(url)
  } else {
    // if not found add new object
    acc.push({[objKey]: [url]})
  }
  return acc;
}, []) // [] is initial value of accumulator

console.log(result)

// array [{"obj0":"picture1","picture2"},{"obj1":"picture1"}]
```

Comment: @vicky : relying on object key order is not safe, since it is not guaranteed, extracting `Object.keys()` is unnecessarily verbose and *possibly* slow. Appropriate way of doing that would be `in` operator, like it is done [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756599/11299053).

Answer (score 2):

You can [use reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)  and store all `url` in array:

```
const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, {name, url})=> {
    let key = name.substring(0, 4);
    a[key] = a[key] || [];
    a[key].push(url);
    return a;
},{})).map(([k, v])=> ({[k]: v}));
```

An example:

```js
let array = [
    {"name":"obj0_property0","url":"picture1"},
    {"name":"obj1_property0","url":"picture1"},
    {"name":"obj0_property1","url":"picture2"}
];

const result = Object.entries(array.reduce((a, {name, url})=> {
    let key = name.substring(0, 4);
    a[key] = a[key] || [];
    a[key].push(url);
    return a;
},{})).map(([k, v])=> ({[k]: v}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I probably, can't make myself clear enough, so I'll just go for another attempt: the point was - if source array is small (like, the one OP has posted) it doesn't make much sense to overburden the code with `reduce()` nested into `Object.entries()` and `map()` chained to it, but if source array happens to be large enough, one may certainly benefit from such approach.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov ok, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Great!:)